How can I return a single object from a mutation using HotChocolate while using OOB UseProjection behavior?
I want to write a mutation using HotChocolate that would change FirstName of a given object (Person) and return the updated object as a single object (rather than an IQueriable).
The Person object has a collection field Parents, I want to use OOB [UseProjection] behavior to avoid over-fetching. I.e. only load and return Parents if parents field was requested.
public class Mutation
{
    [UseMutationConvention]
    public Person? UpdateFirstNameAsync([ID] Guid personId, string newName)
    {
       // update person
       // save person

       // ??? how do I reload the person here so that Parents field is 
       // only loaded if it was requested?
    }
}

(using example inspired by HotChocolate documentation)
I can accomplish this by inspecting the resolver context and including .Include clause if Parents were requested:
  ...
  var parentsFieldRequested = resolverContext.FieldSelection.SelectionSet.Selections
        .OfType<FieldNode>()
        .Any(selection => selection.Name.Value == "parents");

    if (parentsFieldRequested)
    {
        query = query.Include(p => p.Parents);
    }

Essentially, is there a way to have this behavior using OOB HotChocolate without having to write this code?
A some sort of [UseProjectionsButReturnASingleObject] attribute, that would allow me to return an IQueriable<Person> but the API would do projection and .FirstOrDefault() on it before returning as a single object (rather than a collection).
I'm on ASP.NET Core 8.
